# Error estimation for field theories

Tags: resource-recommendations, field-theory, perturbation-theory, error-analysis, approximations

I am looking for resources on error estimation for field theories, both the error due to perturbation theory and measurement error. In other words, consider a field theory of a field $\phi$, with some differential operator $D$ such that

\begin{equation}
D\phi = 0
\end{equation}

with (real) initial conditions $\phi(0, x) = \phi_0(x)$, $\phi_{,i}(0, x) = \pi_0^i(x)$. Let's assume

1. We do not have the actual solution, so that we are only considering the solution $\phi'$ to a simpler differential operator $D'$
2. We do not have the actual initial conditions, but only up to experimental error $\bar{\phi}_0$ and $\bar{\pi}_0^i$, such that $\phi_0 = \bar{\phi}_0 + \delta \phi_0$ and $\pi^i_0 = \bar{\pi}^i_0 + \delta \pi^i_0$

Given this, as well as bounds on various parameters on $D$ versus $D'$ (upper bounds on the function, coupling constants, etc), and the bounds on the deltas of the initial conditions, what would be the error estimates we can take on the solution?

Also, given not $\phi_0$ and $\pi^i_0$, but rather a set of punctual measurements (as we get in real life), what would be the set of possible initial conditions we can assume, as well as this influence on the error estimates? And inversely, we do not actually get the measure of our final field state but also a set of punctual measurement. In other words, take a set of initial measurements $\{ M^i_k \}$ and final measurements $\{ M^f_k \}$, the chain of ideas is

\begin{eqnarray}
\{ M^i_k \} &\to& \{ (\bar{\phi}_0, \bar{\pi}^i_0) | \text{Initial conditions agree with measurements} \} \\
&\to& \text{Time evolution to $\phi(x, T)$}\\
&\to& \{ M^f_k \pm \delta M^f_k \}
\end{eqnarray}

with the error $\delta M^f_k$ influenced by the various errors we have accumulated along the way (error on initial measurements, due to the uncertainty of which initial conditions we actually have, etc etc).

I haven't been able to find a lot of resources for this. For point 1, I did find Murdock's Perturbation : Theory and Methods, which does contain some informations on error estimates (although only for ODEs), but most other sources I can find are either for numerical analysis, which isn't really what I am looking for, or exceedingly mathematical papers on topics such as Strichartz estimates and such. For point 2, I haven't managed to find much so far.

Are there good introductions on both of those topics? And what would at least be the correct terminology for those concepts to search for?

Comment: To be honest, it seems very strange. May be I have not ehough experience in QFT but when you calculate something physical (for instance, cross-section or decay width) in QFT, the significant errors come from loop correction. For instance, in SM loop corrections explain 1% errors (roughly speaking) in gauge boson masses (may be I am not correct but the idea is clear).

Comment: I am looking more for classical field theories, where you simply have the field configuration at an initial time.

Comment: (1) What you are asking looks very difficult. I think most of the time a "practical" approach is used: sample a few initial conditions within the experimental uncertainties, integrate the set of PDE and see how spread are the final states. If you have only a few spatial points to resolve the initial conditions, you may also add smaller scale fluctuations to the initial conditions to see if they impact the above spread.

Comment: (2) I think that point (1) is essentially what you can do in practice when your PDEs are non-linear. If you have linear PDE, then an analysis of the Fourier modes (i.e. finding the dispersion relations) can help to understand the role of the small scale fluctuations that may be there but can not be experimentally sampled (do they grow or decay?).

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a particularly satisfying answer to such a problem, but a pretty good resource on the topic would be [A Posteriori Estimates for Partial Differential Equations](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110203042) by Sergey Repin, in particular section 9.6.